# What does a cognitive linguistics researcher actually do in practice?

Tags: research, cognitive-linguistics

What would a cognitive linguistics researcher do on a daily basis, and how would they go about conducting this research?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Is there any particular field you're interested in? What kind of research?

Comment: I'm looking for any sort of input from a linguistics researcher, but more specifically what somebody studying cognitive linguistics would do. That's not to say I'm not looking for input from computational linguistics, historical linguistics, etc.

Comment: Ok, but we need that the questions be more focused. As a rule of thumb, if the question needs a whole book to be answered, then it's not a good question according to SE standards and should therefore be closed. We don't want that, of course. So I suggest that you add the cognitive linguistics detail to your question and perhaps tell us what you already know about it. That way, other users can target the specific problems you're facing and help you more effectively. As a last remark, you can also ask other similar questions, one for each of the subfields you mentioned.

Comment: Updated! I think I'm just carrying habits over from Quora! :) haha